# Xsl sum() <traffic> of <users> with the same name

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm beginner in xsl.
I need to calculate sum traffic of users with same name **(name NOT "name" + "last name")**, for example calculate sum of traffic of all users with name "Jonh". And xsl version should be only 1.0.

I found a topic with the same problem

> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/xmlandnetfx/thread/c9f09ba6-1c79-43df-bbc2-3966710fff23

I was try to use that:

```
<span>Total: <xsl:value-of select="sum(//user[contains(name,'Jonh')]../traffic)" /></span>
```

or

```
<span>Total: <xsl:value-of select="sum(//user[contains(name,'Jonh')]/traffic)" /></span>
```

but there is no effect. It does not calculate the sum.
Can anyone help me to find a solution.

XML FILE

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='traffic.xsl'?>
<root>
   <user>
       <name>Jonh Connor</name>
       <traffic>800</traffic>
   </user>
   <user>
       <name>John Kennedy</name>
       <traffic>200</traffic>
   </user>
   <user>
       <name>Jack London</name>
       <traffic>100</traffic>
   </user>
   <user>
       <name>Sema Schlumberger</name>
       <traffic>300</traffic>
   </user>
   <user>
       <name>Jack Vorobey</name>
       <traffic>700</traffic>
   </user>
   <user>
       <name>John Lennon</name>
       <traffic>500</traffic>
   </user>
   <user>
       <name>John Romero</name>
       <traffic>4003</traffic>
   </user>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second expression works ...

```
 <xsl:value-of select="sum(//user[contains(name,'Jonh')]/traffic)" />
```

I tested this and it works. Please note apparent typo in names: 'Jonh' and 'John' .

Note, although your expression is correct, if you can rely on the structure implied by your sample input, when the context node is the document root, then you may prefer a more efficient solution:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="sum(root/user/name[contains(.,'Jonh')]/../traffic)" />
```

### Caveat

This form of expression does not distinguish between names and parts of names. So if you sum on 'Rom', you will get 4003 due to the fact that the last name 'John Romero' includes 'Rom'. If this is not a desired result, then you need to clarify the rules for matching.

Comment: Thank you Sean B. Durkin, it was simply typo :), and about occurrence in 'John Romero' example, i think than better solution to use starts-with function.

Answer (score 0):

The second expression works fine. Anyway, I'd rather remove `contains()` function from the expression, since it can lead to mistakes in your calculations. To get results only for users with name "John" you should use the example below:

```
<span>Total: <xsl:value-of select="sum(/root/user[name = 'Jonh']/traffic)" /></span>
```